# Tabularx "absorb?" columns for specific rows

Tags: tabularx

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.1\textwidth}|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
 a & b & c & $\varphi_{1}$&  $\varphi_{2}$&  $\varphi_{3}$&  $\varphi_{4}$&  $\varphi_{5}$&  $\varphi_{6}$&  $\varphi_{7}$& $\varphi_{8}$  \\
\hline
 0      & 0& 0 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 0      & 0& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 0      & 1& 0 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\

\hline
 0      & 1& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\

\hline
 1      & 0& 0 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 0& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 1&  0&  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 1& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
Anzahl der Welten & 1& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1

\end{tabularx}
```

I want the last one with "Anzahl der Welten" to skip the first two 1 what's the command for that?

Comment: If I understand what you want, it should be `\multicolumn{3}{l|}{Anzahl der Welten}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\multicolumn{number of columns to unite}{column specification}{contents}`

Here: `\multicolumn{3}{l|}{Anzahl der Welten}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
 a & b & c & $\varphi_{1}$&  $\varphi_{2}$&  $\varphi_{3}$&  $\varphi_{4}$&  $\varphi_{5}$&  $\varphi_{6}$&  $\varphi_{7}$& $\varphi_{8}$  \\
\hline
 0      & 0& 0 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 0      & 0& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 0      & 1& 0 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 0      & 1& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 0& 0 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 0& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 1&  0&  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
 1      & 1& 1 &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{Anzahl der Welten} &  1& 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1& 1 & 1
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]